# SQL Query Results not printing the first row items

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, row

I want to print my query results into a table. I have placed a limit in my query to fetch only 5 rows. And it does fetch 5 rows from my DB. But when I print my results into an HTML table, the first row in the result is not printed. I can't find anything wrong with my code. Help please!

Here is how I did it:

```
<table style="border:none; width:790px;; margin:10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th  class="header">ID</th>
        <th  class="header">Client Name</th>
        <th  class="header">Driver's License</th>
        <th  class="header">Social Security</th>
        <th  class="header">Phone Number</th>
        <th  class="header">Email Address</th>
        <th  class="header">Date Signed Up</th>
    </tr>  
<?php

$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ($i & 1) { //odd rows
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['cid'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['license'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['ss1'].' / '.$row['ss2'].' / '.$row['ss3'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['phone1_1'].'-'.$row['phone1_2'].'-'.$row['phone1_3'];
            if ($row['phone1_ext'] != NULL ) {
                echo ' ext. '.$row['phone1_ext'].'</td>';
            } else { 
                echo '</td>';
            }
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_odd">'.$row['registered'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    } else { //even rows
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['client_id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['license'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['ss1'].' / '.$row['ss2'].' / '.$row['ss3'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['phone1_1'].'-'.$row['phone1_2'].'-'.$row['phone1_3'];
            if ($row['phone1_ext'] != NULL ) {
                echo ' ext. '.$row['phone1_ext'].'</td>';
            } else { 
                echo '</td>';
            }
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="entry_even">'.$row['registered'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

        $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the limit? are all rows displayed then? also, show the exact SQL query that is used

Answer (score 0):

Without any SQL, I would make the following changes:

```
<?php

$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $row_class = ($i % 2) ? "entry_even" : "entry_odd";

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['cid']."</td>\n";
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname']."</td>\n";
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['license']."</td>\n";
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['ss1'].' / '.$row['ss2'].' / '.$row['ss3']."</td>\n";
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['phone1_1'].'-'.$row['phone1_2'].'-'.$row['phone1_3'];
        if ($row['phone1_ext'] != NULL ) {
        echo ' ext. '.$row['phone1_ext']."</td>\n";
        } else { 
        echo "</td>\n";
        }
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['email']."</td>\n";
    echo '<td class="' . $row_class . '">'.$row['registered']."</td>\n";
    echo '</tr>';

    $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers guys!

But I found what was messing this up. It was a single line I placed after the query AND before `$i=1;`. Here was that line:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

This fetched the first row from the array already that's why when I fed the array through the loop, the first $row has been removed already.